# Why is my Animation Drawables skipping frames

Tags: java, android

I have 2 animation drawables that skips frames infinitely.

It runs but the skipping frames is bothersome, slowing the program.

And what does Background Partial concurrent mark sweep mean?

How do i fix this?

Log results

```
I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 46(1696B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 6% free, 57MB/61MB, paused 20.931ms total 27.744ms
I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 18(736B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 5% free, 65MB/69MB, paused 6.151ms total 19.613ms
I/Choreographer: Skipped 47 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer: Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer: Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer: Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

here is the program:

```
public class IntroActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AnimationDrawable animateOcean;
    private AnimationDrawable animateSkull;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro);

        new CreateAnimationDrawableOcean().execute();
        new CreateAnimationDrawableSkull().execute();


        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {

                  final  Drawable img = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.map, null);

                  final  ImageView map = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.map_img);

                  map.post(new Runnable() {

                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                        map.setImageDrawable(img);
                  }
                  });
            }
        }
        };
        new Thread(runnable).start();

}
//turns on and off background animation of ocean
private void animateOcean(boolean stat){
    final ImageView oceanBackground = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.OceanView);

    if(stat){
        oceanBackground.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                animateOcean.start();
            }
        });
    }

    else{
        oceanBackground.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                animateOcean.stop();
            }
        });
    }


}

//turns off and on animation of skull with stones
private void animateSkull(boolean stat){

    final ImageView skull = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.skull_image);


    if(stat){
        skull.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                animateSkull.start();
            }
        });
    }

    else
    {
        skull.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                animateSkull.stop();
            }
        });
    }

}

private class CreateAnimationDrawableOcean extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Drawable>{
    @Override
    protected Drawable doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        Drawable img =  ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.ocean_movie, null);
        animateOcean = (AnimationDrawable) img;

        return img;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Drawable drawable) {
        super.onPostExecute(drawable);

        ImageView oceanBackground = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.OceanView);
        oceanBackground.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        animateOcean(true);


    }
}


private class CreateAnimationDrawableSkull extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Drawable>{
    @Override
    protected Drawable doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        Drawable img = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.skull_movie, null);

        animateSkull = (AnimationDrawable) img;
        return img;



    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Drawable drawable) {
        ImageView skull = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.skull_image);

        skull.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        animateSkull(true);



    }
}
}
```

Comment: Just as the warning says `The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.` You may need to push some of the processing being done off the main thread.

Comment: How do i push some of the processing being done off the main thread. I thought i was doing this by creating 2 classes extended from AsyncTask, as well as the 2 runnable functions(  animateSkull(boolean), animateOcean(boolean) ). As well as the new thread i created in the OnCreate function